# Sending an Email through SendGrid without Authentication

Tags: azure, authentication, sendgrid

I have just signed up for SendGrid and have been able to successfully email but I was wondering if it is possible to send emails with no authentication? At the moment I have only been able to send using authentication.

Thankyou in advance for your response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to send without authentication?

Imagine that from SendGrid's perspective, how are they going to know that it is you sending email (and hence bill you for it) and how are they going to prevent just anybody connecting and bulk sending whatever they want!

This is known as an [Open SMTP Relay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mail_relay) and is generally considered a very bad thing™ ;)

The good thing though, is that it is very difficult to find an application that doesn't support SMTP authentication. Whatever you are using will have a setting to configure auth, and once its set up you can likely forget all about it being there.

However, if you can give an idea of your use case, we can probably help you figure out a better way of achieving your goal...

Comment: Thankyou for this answer @Micheal B. I didn't think it was possible but was just confirming before moving on. I just need it for a program that we use at work, but we can just add the authentication feature into it. Thankyou again!